# Run JMeter sampler sequentially

Tags: jmeter

Actually I have  2 sampler in my jmx file second sampler is depend on first sample i have use regular expression extractor to extract value also used synchrozing timer and uniform random timer and use ${__threadNum} function to find order of execution of thread I used 50 users and run then someusers in sequence order but suddenly seen order is change (1-2-5-3-4)like that I want every sampler  execute sequntially order

Answer (score 0):

Each user executes samplers sequentially (upside down) by default so you don't need to do anything at all

[image]

- [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function won't do anything but only show you the number of current thread (virtual user)
- [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) will "group" virtual users so specific sampler will be executed by X users at exactly the same moment, the sequential order of execution is not guaranteed, the sample result with the lowest response time will appear first in the .jtl results file/listeners no matter which user has initiated the call

If you want first run 2 samplers with 1st user, then run 2 samplers with 2nd user, etc. then you won't have any concurrency (i.e. you will have 1 active user at any stage of the test)

If this is what you're looking for you can put your Samplers under the [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller):

[image]